# what is the maximum and minimum date shown by calenderview in android

Tags: java, date

what is the maximum and minimum date shown date pickerDialog in android

I need know what maximum and minimum date shown by date picker android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such defined max date and min date for calendar view in android. You can view the [CalendarView: android:maxDate and android:minDate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html#attr_android:maxDate).

If you see at the source then it says that the the maximal date shown by this calendar view in mm/dd/yyyy format. So it means that the max date should be 12/31/9999 and min date respectively should be 01/01/0001